# Downloading flask-generated html page

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to put a button on a flask-generated web page and let a user download the html page as a file when the user clicks the button. What I imagine is something like saving the rendered html into `BytesIO` and send it via `send_file`, but I can't find how to save the rendered page into a file object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import StringIO
from flask import Flask, send_file, render_template

def page_code():   
    strIO = StringIO.StringIO()
    strIO.write(render_template('hello.html', name='World'))
    strIO.seek(0)
    return send_file(strIO,
                     attachment_filename="testing.txt",
                     as_attachment=True)
```

It is not tested but should give you an idea.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't expect ```render_template``` to return the whole html page in a string, I thought it would be doing more than that behind the scene because the API document doesn't say anything about its return value, or maybe I just missed it. This solves the problem.

Comment: This code does not work under python3. Any ideas how to correct it?

Comment: @gtomer Did you ever figure out a way to get it working in Python3? Trying to download a rendered html template myself by running into this assertion exception:

```assert isinstance(data, bytes), "applications must write bytes"
AssertionError: applications must write bytes```

Comment: @user15771504 - nope

Answer (score 0):

@gtomer Using the input from the thread, I may have figured out a solution that helped eliminate the **AssertionError** (by using BytesIO since on StringIO) that worked for me. This is on Python39.

```
xx = asteriod.query.filter_by(order_number=tagVV).first()
yy = toposphere.query.filter_by(order_number=tagVV).all()
            
apple = io.BytesIO()
apple.write(render_template("receipt2.html", x12=yy, x13=ww, x14=xx).encode('utf-8'))
apple.seek(0)
return send_file(apple, attachment_filename="testing.html", as_attachment=True)
```